# Regex not matching in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am reading a file and am trying to print out the matches for two regular expressions separated by a disjunction. How can I print out both of the matches while keeping the disjunction?

```
open(my $fh, $ARGV[0]) or die "ARGV[0] not found!\n";

while(my $line = <$fh>){
    if ($line =~ /(NNPS\S+)|(DT\S+ JJ\S+ JJ\S+ NN\S+)/){
        print $line, "\n", $1,  "\n", $2
    }
}
```

The input will be:

```
NNPS/Helicopters MD/will NN/patrol DT/the JJ/temporary JJ/no-fly NN/zone IN/around NNP/New NNP/Jersey POS/'s
```

And the output will be:

```
Line 1
NNPS/Helicopters
DT/the JJ/temporary JJ/no-fly NN/zone
```

Comment: Some sample input and output would go a long way towards clarifying what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is never going to match both sides of the `|` in a single match, that's why it's an or.  You should match with a `/g` to get all possible matches, using just one capture group, and collect them in a list.

```
if (my @matches = $line =~ /(NNPS\S+|DT\S+ JJ\S+ JJ\S+ NN\S+)/g){
    print join "\n", @matches;
}
```

Comment: If there is a regex that matches on a different line (e.g., line 2), how would the code be adjusted such that the matches are printed out on a new line? Right now, it is being printed on the same line.

Comment: @SagarSamtani You'd either concatenate everything together into one line, or you properly parse the format instead of using regexes.

Comment: @SagarSamtani You're going to have to ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

The "disjunction" is called **alternation** in perish talk. 
Given:

```
"abc123" =~ m/(abc|123)/;

print $1; # abc
```

Try this out (note the global search modifier **\g**):

```
while ("abc123" =~ m/(abc|123)/g){
   print "$1\n";
}
```

Comment: I think you mean _alternation_.